# Automatically deploy a contract with generated Web3js code

Tags: web3js, contract-deployment, compilation

I want a command line tool which having only contract source would automatically not only compile it but also automatically create the JS code which can deploy the contract through Web3.js (using user provided variables for symbol and token name).

Does such a tool exist? If not, is there an easy way to create it?

Comment: Truffle does this as well as any post-deployment configuration tasks you want handled automatically via migration scripts. `$ truffle migrate` does it all.

Comment: his requirement is create that js file in which smart contract function will be called using web3 library. He want to generate it automatically. All he will do is writing smart contract and else will generate on its own. Like Remix where it gives us a simulation of all the function to call.